# iOS App crashing on click of a text field or a textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

My app has many views with lot many forms. When I try to play with my app, clicking and scrolling every where. I do find my app crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I try to click on a text field or a text view. I do get the following errors in different crashes:

```
 1. `-[__NSDictionaryM keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16589960
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16589960'`

 2. `-[__NSSetM keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ee3650
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSetM keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ee3650'`

 3. `-[NSISLinearExpression keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14760360
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSISLinearExpression keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14760360'`

 4. `-[__NSCFString keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e00e10
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e00e10'`
```

What could be the source of the crash?

Comment: A stacktrace is the place to start so you can figure out where in your code this is happening.  If you want our help then please also post it here.

Comment: Are you implementing the UITextViewDelegate or UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: Its always happening at textFieldDidBeginEditing: or textViewDidBeginEditing:. I have implemented both UITextViewDelegate and UITextFieldDelegate depending on the view containing the UI Objects.

Comment: You should enable Zombies.  It looks very much like your one of your delegate objects has been deallocated and the memory has been reallocated to a different object type, resulting in the unrecognised selector message

Comment: How is your scrolling implemented? CollectionView/TableView etc...? Where are you setting your TextView/TextField delegates?

Comment: Are you also using the UIScrollViewDelegate?

Comment: I think , i have not implemented the uiscrollview delegates

Comment: @user2903299, where did you implemented keyboardDidShow: method? Is this is associated as a selector to a Keyboard notification?

Comment: no, i have no where implemented keyBoardDidShow method, crash happens when i click on the text field or the text view

Comment: Are you implementing -(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView and -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField?

Comment: looks like your textfield and textView are getting released. Can you please check whether you gave strong references to them or not?

Comment: yes all of them have strong reference

Comment: I think its better if you add some code. Otherwise it could be difficult to answer.

Comment: There is no code written inside textViewDidBeginEditing:

Comment: textViewShouldBeginEditing:
-[**** keyboardDidShow:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1815a210

Comment: I get the above log when i click on the text view after playing around

Comment: There should be a boolean return value in that method. For testing put "return yes" in textViewShouldBeginEditting